# Is a templatized UDL possible?

Tags: c++, templates, udl

I created an UDL for Base 3 integers with compile time checks for invalid digits and overflow. Additionally, I wanted to allow for digit separators.

I came up with the below solution that works well. Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

constexpr int Base = 3;
constexpr char DigitSeparator = '\'';

// Template Helpers
// Base case
template <int lastRecursionInteger>
constexpr int baseXinteger(){ return lastRecursionInteger; }

// Recursion
template <int part, char currentDigit, char...digitCharacterPack>
constexpr int baseXinteger() {

    // Ignore digit separators
    if constexpr (currentDigit == DigitSeparator)
        return baseXinteger<part, digitCharacterPack...>();
    else {
        // Check for valid digits
        static_assert((currentDigit >= '0') and (currentDigit < ('0' + Base)), "Invalid Digit");
        // Check for potential integer overflow
        static_assert(part <= ((std::numeric_limits<int>::max() - (currentDigit-'0')) / Base) , "Overflow");

        // Recursive calculation of resulting integer
        return baseXinteger<(Base * part) + (currentDigit - '0'), digitCharacterPack...>();
    }
}

// Definition of the UDL operator using the above template helper
template <char... c> int operator""_3 () {
    return baseXinteger < 0, c...>();
}

// Test
int main() {
    std::cout << 1'11_3 << '\n';
    //std::cout << 123_3 << '\n';
    //std::cout << 2222222222222222222222222222222222222_3 << '\n';
}
```

Looking at that, I wanted to immediately have also Base 4 or Base 5 or BASE n UDLs. If you look in the code, I would just need to change the initial constexpr "Base" and the UDL itself.

Is there any mechanism on how to make this more generic, using templates?

---

### Edit

With macros it is easy, but ugly. Can it be done with templates

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <array>

constexpr char DigitSeparator = '\'';

// Template Helpers
// Base case
template <int Base, int lastRecursionInteger>
constexpr int baseXinteger(){ return lastRecursionInteger; }

// Recursion
template <int Base, int part, char currentDigit, char...digitCharacterPack>
constexpr int baseXinteger() {

    // Ignore digit separators
    if constexpr (currentDigit == DigitSeparator)
        return baseXinteger<Base, part, digitCharacterPack...>();
    else {
        // Check for valid digits
        static_assert((currentDigit >= '0') and (currentDigit < ('0' + Base)), "Invalid Digit");
        // Check for potential integer overflow
        static_assert(part <= ((std::numeric_limits<int>::max() - (currentDigit-'0')) / Base) , "Overflow");

        // Recursive calculation of resulting integer
        return baseXinteger<Base, ((Base * part) + (currentDigit - '0')), digitCharacterPack...>();
    }
}

// Definition of the UDL operator using the above template helper
//template <char... c> int operator""_3() { return baseXinteger <3, 0, c...>(); }

// Defining a macro. Yucc
#define m(b) template <char... c> int operator""_##b##() { return baseXinteger <b, 0, c...>(); }

m(2)
m(3)
m(4)
m(5)
m(6)
m(7)
m(8)
m(9)

// Test
int main() {
    std::cout << 111_2 << '\n'
        << 111_3 << '\n'
        << 111_4 << '\n'
        << 111_5 << '\n'
        << 111_6 << '\n'
        << 111_7 << '\n'
        << 111_8 << '\n'
        << 111_9 << '\n';
}
```

Comment: You cannot change the name of the template in the template, like `""_3` to `""_4`. With a macro possibly, but I wouldn't touch that. Macros creating templates - Yuck!.

Comment: I don't think a macro is going to solve it. Macro's don't do math. 3+1 is just that, 3+1. You're not looking for `operator""_3+1`.

Comment: make `base` a template argument and then you can write `template <char... c> int operator""_4 () {  return baseXinteger <4, 0, c...>(); }`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: No, this is not what I wanted. See my edit above. Easy with macros, but I guess not possible with templates . . .

Comment: Aside: you can do most of this [with fold expressions](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66471a4062bd94be)

Comment: [Overflow checking too](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/527ea2758c6018be)